# 9v AC 2000mA power adaptor for a 9v AC 1000mA device

Tags: power, ac, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I need to replace a 9v AC 1000mA adapter for a 9v AC 1000mA device but all I've been able to find is a 9v AC 2000mA adapter.

Will this work or will it fry my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.
The voltage matches (important point #1), and the adapter can deliver 1000 mA *or more* (important point #2).

The current rating for a power adapter says how much it can provide; how much it actually *does* provide is up to the load.
In other words, any adapter that is 9 V and 1000+ mA should work just fine.

Comment: Using an adapter rated for a higher current is not always safe!  The adapter output voltage may be only be well regulated in the current range for which it was designed, and the open-circuit voltage can be much higher than the rating.